# How to create multiple directory inside docker volume

Tags: postgresql, docker

Actually i need to create directories inside volume & have to use that directories to mount container.

i need example commands for this.?

Comment: where is your problem ?

Answer (score 1):

- `mkdir ~/first`
- `mkdir ~/second`
- `touch ~/first/file1`
- `touch ~/second/file2`
- docker run -it -v ~/first:/first -v ~/second:/second ubuntu find / -name file*`

  /second/file2

  /first/file1

using this you can mount multiple files in an containers

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but my aim is -> is there way to create multiple directories inside volume.?

Comment: mkdir takes multiple arguments, simply run mkdir dir_1 dir_2